# How I could create a theme selector for Django (ideas, advices, ...)

Tags: jquery, python, css, django

I'm developping and improving my `Django` website and I would like to get advices about `graphic charts` and what I can do with Django.
When I'm developping my software, I adopted a graphic chart according to my compagny's colors (blue and white) in order to display a good trial version.

But, if I have to develope my project for another compagny, let suppose with "green and red" graphic chart, I have to modify all my CSS files and replace original white & blue colors by green & red.

My question is :

**How I could write a script which will be located in a tools menu in my Django website with a `theme selector` ?**

For example, I had to create some CSS file and choose the good one by checking a case ? Then, the website will adopt colors from this theme.

Something like this in `Dolibarr Software` :

[image]

For the moment, I'm just getting some ideas / processes and if someone had already made this kind of things ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of simplest ways with predefined css themes - you can include stylesheet in your base template with condition (stylevar is one of customizable site options):

```
{% if stylevar == 'default_css' %}
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endif %}

{% if stylevar == 'fancy_css' %}
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/fancy.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Ok, and If I want to select the good stylesheet directly in my Django website, I have to create a selectbox and replace `stylevar == ' ' ` by what I've checked ?

Comment: @Valentin stylevar here is variable passed to template context from view... You need to decide where you will save that user setting (db or session or cookie) and then create form which will have select box (why not) with predefined style choices. When this form is submitted you should update user style setting.

Comment: Ok it's what I'm thinking. I have to see How I can create this kind of things but you helped me very well !